# How to do Odoo Leave Type Filter(user has only display 2 leave type admin need to display all)?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

user(employee) has to display only 2 leave type and admin(HR officer) has to display all leave type

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by creating one field in 'hr.holidays.status' model like whether this leave is visible to manager or not.

By overwriting onchange of holiday_status_id and return domain as per logged in user by checking whether it is a manager or not.